# After attempting to ge the instruction of vide.js correct, does this code look correct?

Tags: video.js

Help with set up instructions of video.js 
I got limited help trying to set up this player:
http://www.videojs.com/docs/setup/
The link instructions are pretty short/(easy for someone more skilled than me), but I need some advice, please. The self-hosted instructions show this:

```
<link href="http://example.com/path/to/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://example.com/path/to/video.js"></script>
<script>
  _V_.options.flash.swf = "http://example.com/path/to/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

The help I got added this code to appropriate file:

```
<link href="http://theurl.com/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://theurl.com/video-js/video-js.css"></script>
<script>
  _V_.options.flash.swf = "http://theurl.com/video-js/video-js.swf"
</script>

 <video id="mp4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="http://theurl.com/uploads/" type='video/mp4' />
 </video>
```

According to the very short instructions at http://www.videojs.com/docs/setup/
does this new added code look right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct, though you'll want to make sure the src attribute of the source tag points to a specific video file that's already been uploaded to the web somewhere.

```
<source src="http://theurl.com/uploads/MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply. Can you please tell me why the scr attribute of the source tag points to a specific file that's already been uploaded? Will it play more than that one file, if that single specific file is entered on that line?